# setting up AWS cygwin -

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Trying to standup GPU server for fast.ai course using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rjRfW4JM2I)

on a windows machine. Stuck at step at 8:07, "Type

```
$bash setup_p2.sh
```

"...multiple errors result:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\python.exe: can't open file 
'/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Anaconda2/Scripts/aws': [Errno 2] No such file or 
directory
setup_p2.sh: line 7: [: =: unary operator expected
setup_p2.sh: line 9: [: =: unary operator expected
setup_p2.sh: line 11: [: =: unary operator expected
Only us-west-2 (Oregon), eu-west-1 (Ireland), and us-east-1 (Virginia) are 
currently supported
```

This is the end of what has been a long painful process standing this up. I never thought one 13-minute video could make me dislike Windows so much.

Comment: It looks like the setup_p2.sh script is trying to invoke the awscli and it's expecting to find it at /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Anaconda2/Scripts/aws. Did you install awscli per the video's instructions (pip install awscli)? Do you actually have a folder named /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Anaconda2/Scripts/ and do you see the aws script there?

Comment: For your system, you probably have Python installed to c:\Program Files\Anaconda2. Or you are using Python3 which installs to .../Anaconda3.

Comment: @jarmod thank you for the reply. I did follow the instructions in the video. They are not explicit in which options to choose when installing Anaconda (e.g., PATH and 'Install for all Users') and with Cygwin it took me a while to realize I have to always run the program as administrator. I have since uninstalled everything and am giving it another shot.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the comment. I was running Anaconda2, as recommended by the video. But even when I pointed Cygwin to the right directory with     cd C:/ProgrmaData/Anconda2/Scripts I was given the aws not found error, even though I could see it physically there.

Comment: http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Awscli_in_cygwin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149718/aws-cli-in-cygwin-how-to-clean-up-differences-in-windows-and-cygwin-style-path